# Origin policies in azure APIM

Tags: xml, azure-api-management

I am learning about azure APIM policies and I have a question.
I have an API with , so in the allow-origin I have to set the origins one by one. If I have many subdomains in a domain (e.g. subdomain1.domain.com, subdomain2.domain.com, etc).

Is there any way to use a regular expression in the origin to set something like https://*.domain.com?

Thanks!